# AWS cloudwatch - prevent alerts for alarm INSUFFICIENT_DATA -> OK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I've autoscale on ec2 instance and I send custom metrics data to cloudwatch for each instance. I've auto create alarm when new instance started but then it will send out alert each time when new instance comes in with INSUFFICIENT_DATA -> OK. I only want to receive alerts when it's Alarm to ok or vice versa. Is there a way to prevent it to send out for state INSUFFICIENT_DATA -> OK ?

Comment: Did you get the solution? If yes Can you please share?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to make your subscription email-json and then use the subscription filter policy. Use the "Message body" option with the following policy:

```
{
  "NewStateValue": [
    "ALARM",
    "OK"
  ],
  "OldStateValue": [
    {
      "anything-but": [
        "INSUFFICIENT_DATA"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now it will only send when its not coming off of INSUFFICIENT_DATA. Unfortunately, I could not get this to work with a basic email subscription. Its likely not sending the data in the JSON format for filtering. This also works with SQS subscriptions as I've used the policy filtering successfully.